# Modern OpenGL: how to update/redraw a large model partially

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

My app uses modern OpenGL and MFC. I have a very large model, which means rendering is heavy and slow. I want to avoid frequent redraw of the large model as much as possible.

I know OpenGL always redraws everything to show updates. What I am looking for is sth like below:

- The large model will be rendered once and then stays as background.
- On top of the model, users can drag&draw line works. During the drag&draw process, the OpenGL will constantly update/redraw the line works(but not the model).
- When users are done with line works, the large model will update once to include the lineworks.

The problem is that how do I make OpenGL only redraw the line works but keep the model as background during the drag&draw?

Comment: Use a [`Framebuffer Object`](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers) to render the 'large' model to a texture and map that texture to a quad that you can show as the  background.  Also a good link [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/).  There's probably a dupe for this somewhere.

Comment: "*I have a very large model, which means rendering is heavy and slow.*" Maybe you should work on that problem. Unless this model is in the hundreds of *millions* of polygons, rendering shouldn't be all that slow.

Comment: @NicolBolas The model normally has millions to billions of triangles.  I want it to run smoothly.  Of course, if the app can handle as large data as possible smoothly, that's the best : )

Comment: @jiechen: "*billions of triangles*" You must have a lot of GPU memory. Even if each vertex is only 8 bytes, that's 8 GB of storage.